# D3js force layout: Dynamic linkDistance according to Levenshtein distance function

Tags: dynamic, d3.js, distance, force-layout

```
var t0 = [  "site",        "how", "social",     "create", "membership"],
    t1 = [ "forum",       "site", "social", "membership", "networking"],
    t2 = ["social",    "network", "create",        "how",       "free"],
    t3 = ["social", "membership",   "site",    "website",       "make"] ;

    function levenshteinDistance (a, b) {
        if (!a.length) return b.length;
        if (!b.length) return a.length;
        return Math.min(
            levenshteinDistance(a.slice(1), b) + 1,
            levenshteinDistance(b.slice(1), a) + 1,
            levenshteinDistance(a.slice(1), b.slice(1)) + (a[0] !== b[0] ? 1 : 0)
        );
    }
    console.log(levenshteinDistance (t0, t1));
    console.log(levenshteinDistance (t0, t2));

    .linkDistance(levenshteinDistance (t0, t1))
```

I need a function which provide a dynamic distance according to data given before Levenshtein distance function. I want to create dynamic linkDistance according to my function. I am putting Levenshtein distance function on same page. I am new here and if I made mistake please confirm me. If you need I will be here to answer your questions.

Comment: Is this for the force layout? If you give a function to `linkDistance`, you'll get called for each link, which should allow you to get the two nodes on that link.

Comment: Yes it is about force layout. I had already attempted to create function but I failed. Can you give me simple way to do? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Assuming that you use the standard data structures, it would be something like `.linkDistance(function(l) { return levenshtein(l.source, l.target); })`. In your distance function, you would need to extract the node positions through the `dx` and `dy` attributes.

Comment: It is hard to me to apply. I need a simple code like that : `.linkDistance(function() {
     for (var i=0;i<10;i++; j=0;j<10;j++)
                                                { 
                                                return levenshteinDistance (ti, tj);
                                                }        
      })` Thank you so much. I was feeling so alone. I have been learning D3 for 2 months. I need more help.

Comment: Ah right, your distance function is based on the names of the nodes. Well in that case you would need to call it something like `levenshtein(l.source.name, l.target.name)` in your `.linkDistance` function.

Comment: My distance function is not based on the names of the nodes. I am creating a new variables for new data in order to use levenshteinDistance function and because of that I want to call them back as to,t1 within the linkDistance() function.It is not related to my nodes or force layout graph. It is additional function within same index.html these t1,t2 things are not my main data I am using json data [link](http://chemicalingredients.com/d3jsdenemeler/deneme6.html)

Comment: So if this data is not related to the force layout, how is it to be used in it?

Comment: If I use `.linkDistance(levenshteinDistance (t0, t1))` alone it is working I need a function which provides each distance for 2 different array groups. As I said before I need just something like that :  `.linkDistance(function() { for (var i=0;i<10;i++; j=0;j<10;j++) { return levenshteinDistance (ti, tj); } })`  Or how can I add this  levenshteinDistance function and data of it to the main json data  =>[please check my sample](http://chemicalingredients.com/d3jsdenemeler/deneme6.html) => [Json data](http://chemicalingredients.com/d3jsdenemeler/deneme.json)

Comment: `.linkDistance` expects a function that returns a single value, not an array of value. It determines the link distance for a single link.

Comment: `.linkDistance(function(d){ return (Math.random() * (400 - 200) + 1);})` It is creating different linkdistance for each nodes I need something like that.